# Generate public key from private key

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-generation

Can we generate a public key from a private key?

Comment: ... for what PKE scheme?

Comment: In RSA, and in normal implementations, yes you can.

Comment: Hello and welcome to security.se. When asking question, please take the time to specify all relevant information. In it's current state, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Also see: [Given a private key, is it possible to derive its public key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696472/given-a-private-key-is-it-possible-to-derive-its-public-key/696545#696545) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

By default, a user’s SSH keys are stored in that user’s `~/.ssh` directory. You can check if your private key is in that directory by listing the contents:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ls
authorized_keys2  id_dsa       known_hosts
config            id_dsa.pub
```

The private key is usually something like `id_dsa` or `id_rsa`. To regenerate the public key part with just a private key, use the `-y` switch to the `ssh-keygen` application and write the output to a corresponding `.pub` file:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

From the 'man ssh-keygen' description:

```
 -y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an
         OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

If you don't know whether your private key is Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) or Rivest Shamir Adleman (RSA), you will have to use the `ssh-keygen` application with the `-f` switch. Make sure the name of your new public key matches the name of your private key.